# Seamlessly know the size of a string containing a null char

Tags: c++, string, macros, null-character

Long question for a very simple & rookie problem BUT yet I need some advise.

#### Background

So I have a binary file that I need to parse. This file starts with some magic string that contains the null char (`\0`). let's define is as `ab\0cd`.

I'm writing a method that returns true if some file starts with the magic string.

#### Attempt 1

```
#define MAGIC_STRING "ab\0cd"

bool IsMagicFile(const wpath& pathFile)
{
    string strData;
    if (!ReadFile(pathFile, strData))
        return false;

    if (strData.size() < 5)
        return false;

    string strPrefix = strData.substr(0, 5);

    if (strcmp(strPrefix.c_str(), MAGIC_STRING) != 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

#### Problem 1

What bothers me with the above code is that I "hardcodedly" assume the size of the magic string is `5`.

what if tomorrow the magic string changes? say:

```
#define MAGIC_STRING "abe\0fcd"
```

the string macro changed and the code no longers work properly.

#### Attempt 2

```
#define MAGIC_STRING "ab\0cd"

bool IsMagicFile(const wpath& pathFile)
{
    string strMagic = MAGIC_STRING;

    string strData;
    if (!ReadFile(pathFile, strData))
        return false;

    if (strData.size() < strMagic.size())
        return false;

    string strPrefix = strData.substr(0, strMagic.size());

    if (strcmp(strPrefix.c_str(), MAGIC_STRING) != 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

#### Problem 2

I supposedly got rid of the hard-coded size problem BUT the size of `strMagic` is not really 5 but 2. string ends with `\0`

#### Attempt 3

```
#define MAGIC_STRING        "ab\0cd"    // CAUTION - MAGIC_STRING & MAGIC_STRING_SIZE must be changes together 
#define MAGIC_STRING_SIZE   5           // CAUTION - MAGIC_STRING & MAGIC_STRING_SIZE must be changes together

bool IsMagicFile(const wpath& pathFile)
{
    string strData;
    if (!ReadFile(pathFile, strData))
        return false;

    if (strData.size() < MAGIC_STRING_SIZE)
        return false;

    string strPrefix = strData.substr(0, MAGIC_STRING_SIZE);

    if (strcmp(strPrefix.c_str(), MAGIC_STRING) != 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

#### Problem 3

This solved the first problem but I still don't get the seamless magic string change I wanted.

#### Question

Is attempt 3 good enough? do you have a better approach?

Comment: You have a tag `C++` in your question => std::string only, not strcmp => Solved. (And `const string` instead of `#define`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the macro definition you could define a constant character array. For example

```
const char MAGIC_STRING[] = "abe\0fcd";
```

In this case the number of characters excluding the terminating zero is equal to

```
sizeof( MAGIC_STRING ) - 1
```

To compare raw bytes you can use standard C function `memcmp` supplying the number of compared bytes that is equal to the expression above.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>

const char MAGIC_STRING[] = "abe\0fcd";

int main() 
{
    std::string s( std::begin( MAGIC_STRING ), std::prev( std::end( MAGIC_STRING ) )  );

    if ( memcmp( s.c_str(), MAGIC_STRING, sizeof( MAGIC_STRING ) - 1 ) == 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "The string starts with the MAGIC_STRING" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
The string starts with the MAGIC_STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that your magic string will contain `\0` then you could write your own `size(string str)`function that will return the correct length by continuing to count after the first `\0`.

If it is not known how many `\0`s there are in the magic string I would suggest you go with attempt 3.

If you need some code to guide you in the right direction for the `size`method, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would avoid using MACROS. Also I would not use functions designed for null-terminated strings like [std::strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). You could check if the beginning of a string contains a particular character sequence using [std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) from the standard `<algorithm>` library:

```
// create a character array to preserve compile time size
// but remember string literals add a null-terminator extra character
const char magic_string[] = "ab\0cd";

bool IsMagicFile(const wpath& pathFile)
{
    string strData;
    if (!ReadFile(pathFile, strData))
        return false;

    // -1 to avoid null terminator from magic_string character array
    return std::equal(magic_string, magic_string + sizeof(magic_string) - 1,
        strData.begin());
}
```

Comment: If the searched string does not begin with the magic string, `std::string::find()` will search the entire string before failing. I would suggest using [`std::string::compare()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) instead: `return strData.compare(0, magic_string.length(), magic_string) == 0;`. Alternatively: `return strData.compare(0, 5, "ab\0cd", 5) == 0;`. Also, `magic_string` will be `"ab"` because the `\0` will be interpreted as a null terminator. You need to specify the correct length when constructing it: `const std::string magic_string("ab\0cd", 5);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are totally right. I decided to go with `std::equal` to avoid constructing a `std::string` as that needed to be constructed from a character array to get the size correct.